# In Shopify, how do you show product variants as thumbnails like DODOCASE?

Tags: javascript, liquid, shopify

I have a product that has color variations. Instead of just a drop down to have color variants, is there a way to show thumbnails of the colors with radio buttons?

Just like how DODOcase does for their color options: http://www.dodocase.com/products/dodocase-for-ipad2

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is being used to generate the drop down so you can generate radio buttons instead. The variant should have the color name in it so you can use that to create a cell with that color as the background.

I can't write up an actual example at the moment, but that should point you in the right direction.